# how to use socket.io with two files?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with Socket.io, I use express and I want two .html files that can send messages to the server.
But one of two files send an error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
add.html:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at add.html:26
```

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Aggiungi una storia</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--!link-->
    <p class="i_link">Storia:</p>
    <textarea name="link" id="Story_Text" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br>
    <!--!name-->
    <p class="i_name">Nome:</p>
    <textarea name="name" id="Story_Name" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <!--!number-->
    <p class="i_number">Numero Atto:</p>
    <textarea name="number" id="Story_Number" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <!--!author-->
    <p class="i_author">Autore:</p>
    <textarea name="author" id="Story_Author" cols="50" rows="1"></textarea><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
​
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();

function myFunction() {
    let link = $('#Story_Text').val();
    let number = $('#Story_Number').val();
    let author = $('#Story_Author').val();
    let name = $('#Story_Name').val();
    console.log(link + number + author + name)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can resolve this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad English!

Answer (score 2):

Did you install socket.io ? `npm install socket.io`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your reference to the "Socket.io" js file isn't correct.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- here -->
```

Please make sure it points to the correct file, check the browser network tab to see if the script is correctly loaded. When it is, the 'io' function will be available

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it cannot find the file `/socket.io/socket.io.js`

https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/#Installation

> By default, the Socket.IO server exposes a client bundle at
> /socket.io/socket.io.js.

Do you have the server running? Otherwise you could try the cdn path to see if that works:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: now send this error:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
file/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NTEdATQ:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6 GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NTEdBJq net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Are you running your website locally without a server? Just guessing here, but that could explain why it wont load the script.